# Maintaining BackStack In Bottom Navaigation

Tags: android, android-fragments

I am using bottomNavigation in my android app. I have 5 fragments A, B, C, D, E. The fragment B contains another fragment says B1. When I backpress on fragment B1, it closes the app. How can I move to fragment B when backpressed from fragment B1.

Here is my code

```
 bottomNavigationView.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(
                item -> {
                    Fragment fragment = null;

                    switch (item.getItemId()) {
                        case R.id.A:
                            fragment = new A();
                            break;
                        case R.id.B:
                            fragment = new B();
                            break;
                        case R.id.C:
                            fragment = new C();
                            break;

                        case R.id.D:
                           fragment = new D();
                           break;

                        case R.id.E:
                            fragment = new E();
                            break;

                    }
                    return loadFragment(fragment);

                });


private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    //switching fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment)
                .commit();
         return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While opening B1 Fragment use this

```
private boolean loadFragmentB1(Fragment fragment) {
//switching fragment
if (fragment != null) {
    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment)
            .commit();
     return true;
```

While opening other fragment except B1 , use this

```
private boolean loadFragment(Fragment fragment) {
    //switching fragment
    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction()
                .addToBackStack(null)
                .replace(R.id.main_fragment, fragment)
                .commit();
        return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

And on activity override onBackPressed like this

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){
    if (getSupportFragmentManager().getBackStackEntryCount() != 0) {
        getSupportFragmentManager().popBackStack();
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
        finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: It's working fine but on backpressed the selected item in bottomnavigation is not changing

Comment: When I back  press on B1 it's going to home fragment, but the selected item in botttom navigation is still pointing to B

Comment: you can change selected item by   navigationView.getMenu().getItem(0).setChecked(true);

Comment: It will always set fragment A, All I want is when the user backpress from B1 it should move to B and when backpressed from B it will move to A and set A as selected item. But I am unable to achieve it

Comment: Let's suppose the user is on B1 fragment and he selects E from the bottom Navigation, when the back is pressed it should move to B1 but it is moving to B